# Search isn't displaying all results

Tags: search

On one particular site, when I do a search, not all relevant results are returned.

Example:

Post Title: This is xxx

Post Content: Hello World, this is xxx.

When searching for 'xxx', the post isn't returned in the search results.

Is this expected behaviour, and how do I fix this?

This is the code for the search template:

```
<?php get_header();  ?>

<div class="vw-page-wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="vw-page-content col-md-8" role="main">

                <?php do_action( 'vw_action_before_archive_posts' ); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'templates/post-box/post-layout-'.vw_get_archive_blog_layout() ); ?>
                <?php do_action( 'vw_action_after_archive_posts' ); ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem exactly was, but I solved it by writing a custom search query:

```
<?php $args = array(
    's' => $_GET['s'],
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$custom_search = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $custom_search->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $custom_search->have_posts() ) : $custom_search->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="block-grid-item">
            <div class="entry-content clearfix pagecategory">
                <h2 class="newstitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;

} else { ?>
    <h2>Your search didn't return any results.</h2>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like this is the fault of the template. There could be another plugin trying to filter things. Also please try https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/